# IBM Optim Insert request wrong behaviour

Tags: database, database-schema, infosphere-spl

I am new here and in the IBM Optim world, so i hope there is someone here who have worked with IBM Optim.

Here is the issue:

I have a production and a testing database environment.
In my production database i have several users (100 approx.), and I did an extract request from this database including PKs, synonyms, packages, etc.

My problem is when i try to perform an insert request of that extraction. In my Table Map Editor i set a Qualifier Source (MAIAR.SISCEL) and a Qualifier Destination (DB_REPORTS.MS_OPTIM, where MS_OPTIM is a user in my destination database). The problem is that most of the objects i extracted from the production database belong to differents users, but when i try to insert that object into the destination database, the insert request changes the name of the original object getting a cloned object in the destination user (MS_OPTIM).

For example, i have a synonym object TC_SISCEL.PG_SYNONYM but when the object is inserted into the destination database, it is renamed as MS_OPTIM.PG_SYNONYM. And that does not work for me. I need to copy the object with the same name as i extracted from my production database.

Please someone help me! I have been trying to figure this problem out almost a week with no solution.

Thank you in advance.
Sami